# Height of a UIView in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an UITableView in which i have an UIView (which contains a label). I would like to fix the UIView height with IB, but it doesn't allow me to do, why? And is there a way to do that?

Or solution 2 :  I would like this UIView to adapt to its containt, with the label font size + label top and bottom spacing, is that possible?
Thx

Comment: What do you mean with "I have an UITableView in which i have an UIView"? Is it a tableFooterView oder tableHeaderView? I don't know any other way to handle a view inside a tableView. Or do you mean a tableViewCell?

Comment: Actually it was a Header before, but i don"t want it to be sticky anymore, so i've moved it in the UITableView, but maybe i cannot do it? I'm pretty new to objective C

Comment: There are two types of headers possible in the tableview: section header (every section can have one) and table header (only one header per table). If you are new to iOS/Objective C please take a look at the TableView programming guide from apple. It will save you much time: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: And yes, it is not possible to handle any other view inside a tableview, only cells, sections header and footer and table header and footer views

Comment: You should make a custom table view cell.  Then you will be able to do whatever you want in your custom cells.  I use this method every time I use a tableview, since it gives you the freedom to easily layout your cells like you want. I can link a tutorial or some code if your interested in that approach.

Comment: Ok i finally added a new UITableViewCell, thx all :)